# UITableView cell text not showing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm not seeing the text for my UITableView show up.. in fact the TableView doesn't appear to be on the screen at all because I cannot select the empty rows.

Strangely, my log in cellForRowAtIndexPath shows up ok with the expected data - I just don't see any on the screen.

```
 -(void)bindFriendsToTable:(NSArray *)friends{
NSLog(@"friends : %@",friends);
[sections removeAllObjects];
[sectionRows removeAllObjects];

[sections addObject:@"Friends"];
[sectionRows setObject:friends forKey:@"Friends"];  

[self.tableView reloadData];
HideActivityIndicator();
```

}

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *cellsection = [sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *rowsInSection = [sectionRows valueForKey:cellsection];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone]; 
cell.textLabel.text = [rowsInSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);

return cell;
```

}

I'm inheriting from a base class which is a UITableViewController, as I have for a dozen other screens in the project. Any idea why I'm not seeing the tableView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any header sections?  If so make sure you return a value for heightForHeaderInSection:

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
      return 66;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is your font colour the same as your background colour? If you set the accessoryType to a checkmark does it display?

```
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Nope, I don't see the Accessory. I tried commenting out the selectionStyle stuff and cannot select the rows.

Comment: hey @Liam using that I can see the checkmark. But still no text.. even changing the cell's backgroundcolor and the textlabel :/

Comment: EDIT: just found out the left side of the table was behind a view, therefore I thought the cells were empty, but were not. thks!

Answer (score -2):

i think u should remove 
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone]; 
and then try it.
and display the other static string in the cell to check the problem.

Comment: From the docs, "The selection style is a backgroundView  constant that determines the color of a cell when it is selected. The default value is UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue. See “Cell Selection Style” for a description of valid constants.".